# Functions with Fourier transform support $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, wavelets

> What kind of functions, $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ are such that $\operatorname{supp} \hat{f} \subset [-\pi,\pi]$?

I am trying to prove that the set $\{V_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ consisting of functions $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \hat{f} \subset [-2^j\pi,2^j\pi]$ is a multiresolution.

I have proven every property except for finding the scaling function $\phi$ such that $\phi (\cdot -k)$ forms a Riesz Basis of $V_0$

Since $V_0$ consists of functions, $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $supp \hat{f} \subset [-\pi,\pi]$ I am trying to get an idea of what $V_0$ "looks like" in order to find this Riesz Basis.  Any ideas or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: they are equal to a continuous function almost everywhere

Comment: $V_0=\{f: supp(\hat{f})\subseteq[-\pi,\pi]\}$ is known as the Paley-Wiener space or space of band limited functions. This space is generated by the integer shifts of the function $\text{sinc}(x)$, which is known as the Shannon wavelet. This is the direct consequence of the Shannon sampling theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Comment: Oh thank you! Now that you say that I remember talking about Shannon wavelets and going through them. Thank you.